# SOQL with OpportunityContactRole

Tags: apex, soql, contact, opportunitycontactrole

I am trying to get all the role from OpportunityContactRole into a list my code

```
OppContactRole = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
OppContactRole = [SELECT Role FROM OpportunityContactRole];
```

and try to add this list VF page. I am getting my result from sOQL as

```
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Owner, Id=00KO0000000J56pMAC}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Landlord, Id=00KO0000000J4hVMAS}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Owner, Id=00KO0000000J4qXMAS}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Owner, Id=00KO0000000J56fMAC}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Landlord, Id=00KO0000000J5P3MAK}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Access to House, Id=00KO0000000J6u7MAC}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Decision Maker, Id=00KO0000000J6u8MAC}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Owner, Id=00KO0000000J5MdMAK}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Landlord, Id=00KO0000000J5OyMAK}, 
OpportunityContactRole:{Role=Owner, Id=00KO0000000J574MAC},
```

In the result you can see that role is getting repeated but not id. I tested with the actual value in env but this list do not contain all the values from salesfroce.
Is this any this i am missing out can you please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting data from the OpportunityContactTole will yield data rows of OCR instances.

If you're looking to display a picklist of possible roles, then you need to do this via a describe.

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html